# gcov creates .gcov files in the current directory. Is there any way to change this?

Tags: c++, gcc, gcov

I'm running gcov/gcc 4.1.2 on RHEL.

When I want to specify a directory for the gcov files. Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run gcov from the directory where you want its files to be created.  You'll have to use the `-o` argument to tell it where to look for the .gcno/.gcda files. See [gcov's docs](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Invoking-Gcov.html#Invoking-Gcov) for more info.

Comment: Did you mean 'Run gcov', or is there something called 'gconv'?

Comment: Also note that gcov should be able to access the necessary source files from CWD.

Comment: @jamessan, here the question is to change the target directory for the gcov files.