# How to move generated (e.g. *.gcov ) files into specified path when using scons

Tags: build, build-process, scons

```
.
|--SConstrut
|----->  currently many *.gcov generated here
|
|`--Output
|   |--> output files 
|   `--GCOVs
|      |--> want all the *.gcov files here
|
 `--Source
    |-- FileA.cpp
    |-- SConscript
```

In the Sconscript file i have

```
    o = env.Program(target, objfiles)
    t = env.Command(target = 'something.txt',
                    source = str(o[0]),
                    action = [ 
                               Mkdir('$PATH_GCOV'),
                               "Run the executable ",
                               "Generate gcov files",
                               "Move('$PATH_GCOV', Glob(os.path.join('#', '*.gcov')",
                               "Other activities"
                              ]
    Depends(t, o)
```

The command line in action

```
"Move('$PATH_GCOV', Glob(os.path.join('#', '*.gcov')"
```

doesnt place the *.gcov files, but if there was only one .gcov file, this would be placed in expected path.

Would like to know how i can place all the generated *.gcov which are currently on the root (where Sconstruct is).
Hope i am able to explain the issue.

Comment: If there is a better way of doing what i want to do ... please suggest an alternative otherwise

Comment: How does the step "Generate the gcov files" look like exactly? Is this a separate command, and can you give an absolute/relative path for specifying where the output files should get created?

Comment: I am translating a project from make to scons ... in make they had the line $(MOVE) *.gcov $(GCOV_OUTPATH)

Comment: Reading through gcov document couldnt understand how i can request it to be generated in a specific path or source path. In one of the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1759475/gcov-creates-gcov-files-in-the-current-directory-is-there-any-way-to-change-th) they mentioned "Run gcov from the directory where you want its files to be created".

Comment: Did you already STW (google, duckduckgo) for the keywords "scons gcov"? The external Tool https://github.com/ptomulik/scons-tool-gcccov seems to do pretty much what you need...

Comment: No .. i have not tried that .. will read through it ... thanks

Comment: In that case, and while you're at it, reading http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html a second time is always worthwile, too.

Comment: Some progress ... using chdir='PathToPlaceGCOV' as fourth argument in the Command Function above resulted in files generated in mentioned path. But i have a chicken and egg problem as i am trying to create the path used in chdir= inside the action object :(